# GITLAB CI - React app build failed but job success

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I currently setting up the gitlab-ci.yml file for my react project.
I don't know why but if the project failed to compile, the gitlab job still success.
We can see in the job details in gitlab :

```
 Creating an optimized production build...
 Failed to compile.
 ./src/pages/page500/Page500.js
   Line 26:81:  Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals
 Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
Running after_script
00:01
Saving cache
00:01
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:02
 Job succeeded
```

Please find below the gitlab-ci.yml file :

```
stages:
    - build_test
    - build_production
    - deploy_test
    - deploy_production

build_test:
    image: node:12.17.0
    stage: build_test
    tags:
        - npm-build
    script:
        - unset CI
        - npm install
        - npm run build:development
    only:
        - development
    artifacts:
        when: on_success
        name: settlement-build-development
        paths:
            - build
        expire_in: 1 hour

build_production:
    image: node:12.17.0
    stage: build_production
    tags:
        - npm-build
    script:
        - unset CI
        - npm install
        - npm run build:production
    only:
        - master
    artifacts:
        when: on_success
        name: settlement-build-production
        paths:
            - build
        expire_in: 1 hour

deploy_test:
    image: alpine
    stage: deploy_test
    tags:
        - deploy
    script:
        - apk add --no-cache rsync openssh
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_dsa
        - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
        - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
        - rsync -rav --delete ./build/ -e 'ssh -p 2222' user@XX.XXX.XX.XX:/var/www/website.com/
    only:
        - development
        
deploy_production:
    image: alpine
    stage: deploy_production
    tags:
        - deploy
    script:
        - apk add --no-cache rsync openssh
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_dsa
        - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
        - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
        - ls -lah ./build/
        - rsync -rav --delete ./build/ -e 'ssh -p 2222' user@XX.XXX.XX.XX:/var/www/website.com/
    only:
        - master
```

And please find the script part of packages.json :

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-app-env --env-file=.env.${BUILD_ENV} build",
    "build:development": "BUILD_ENV=development npm run build",
    "build:production": "BUILD_ENV=production npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:cov": "npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Someone already have this problem with gitlab ?

THanks in advance

Comment: its because of the eslint rule
Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals
try adding
 // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
in that file where its defined in and rebuild

Comment: Thanks @Avinash but i can not add this line before each lines in my software you know

Comment: And i just try, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem you will need to make your build fails explicitly!

To do so, you will need to just add `|| exit 1` if your build fails like that:

```
"build:production": "BUILD_ENV=production npm run build || exit 1",
```

This will make the CI stop and `exit 1;`